# What is the proper way to implement MVC pattern in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a clean MVC project. 
So is it good or bad idea to use NSNotificationCenter's observers for communication between  UIViews and ViewControllers?

For example in the CustomView.m i make a button:

```
- (void) makeSomeButton{
....
 [bt addTarget:self action:@(buttonWasClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
...
}

- (void) buttonWasClicked {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"buttonWasClicked" object:nil];
}
```

And in the viewCotroller.m i'm adding observer in init section:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {  // 
       [self.view addSubview: [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame ...]];     
       .....
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
         selector:@(buttonWasClicked) name:@"buttonWasClicked" object:nil];
       .....
    }

    then 
    - (void) buttonWasClicked{
     // button was clicked in customView so do something 
    }
```

If it's not correct, please, explain what is the proper way to implement MVC pattern in iOS app?

Comment: Is UIViewController part of the 'V' graph or the 'C' graph??  I personally prefer to think of it as top of the food chain in the 'view' part of MVC, and think MVC is best implemented by shifting 'control' code elsewhere and considering ViewController an administrator of views

Comment: UIViewController is very much the C, the Views are UIViews. Your UIView subclasses should be stupid.

Comment: Ah but is it??  Why are all of its hooks so view-centric?   Your app delegate is the controller.  When you decouple model-control logic from viewControllers they suddenly become reusable units, try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Notification Center shouldn't be used in this scenario.

The pattern I would use here is delegation.

in your CustomView, declare a protocol, with some method,

at the top of your header:

```
@protocol CustomViewDelegate : NSObject

- (void)customViewDidSelectButton;

@end
```

in the interface.

```
@interface CustomView : NSObject

---

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CustomViewDelegate> delegate;

---

@end
```

in the implementation:

```
- (void) buttonWasClicked {
 [self.delegate customViewDidSelectButton];
}
```

**In the View Controller Observing**

in the implementation file add `<CustomViewDelegate>` (same place you put TableViewDelegate etc..)

and then when you create the `CustomView` set is delegate to self.

implement the delegate method:

```
 - (void)customViewDidSelectButton {
     // button was clicked in customView so do something 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! I thought about delegation but making delegates of UIVew seems strange to me.  What if i have situation for example when "A" viewController need to popViewContrTo "B" VController and at the same time "B" VController need to update some information in it. So I should add another delegation to "B" rather than use NotificationCenter for notifying both of them?

Comment: Delegates from UIView is fine, UITableView, UICollectionView, UIScrollView are all subclasses of UIView.

In the case you have explained:

So I am assuming that both these ViewControllers A and B are in memory, otherwise they wouldn't respond to the notification.

If you are not passing around model object, you can update information in viewController B in the prepareForSegue method on UIViewController, this will give you enough time

Comment: there are plenty of view subclasses which use delegation: UITableView, UIPickerView, UITextField, UITextView, UIScrollView, etc etc

Comment: I know that many of standart views from Cocoa use delegation, i was just a bit confused by using delegation in my own views for routine tasks as "notify controller that some button was clicked". Anyway i see it now from different side. Thank you for your answers!